# Applying conditional formatting with CFSpreadsheet

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfspreadsheet

In continuation of a previous thread, I've reached pretty close to where I want and have learned a lot. I'm under CF10 on a MSSQL Server 2008 environment. I have a report I'm generating using cfspreadsheet and then spitting out values based on whether a user has an app  enabled it will be output as "Yes" and if not output as "No" in the excel spreadsheet.

Problem is, I need to make it a little easier on the eye and so I wanted to see if it was possible to apply conditional formatting to where if the 3 columns with 3 different apps is Y then it will be green and if N it will be red.

Any suggestions or examples would be great, thanks!

Comment: My suggestion is to create a structure for each format you intend to use, including plain jane.  Then use conditional logic to pick the structure in whatever formatting function you are using.  There are two of those mentioned in the answers posted so far.

Answer (score 3):

Like I mentioned [in your other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17985050/104223), if you return  `bit` values (not strings), it is simple to apply a custom cell format. But you must use the spreadsheet functions, rather than cfspreadsheet (which does not support custom formatting).

Here is an expanded example to demonstrate how you could incorporate conditional color formatting:

```
<cfscript>
    // build sample query 
    // note: values must be numeric and NOT text/varchar
    qData = queryNew("");
    queryAddColumn(qData, "AppNameAlpha", "bit", listToArray("0,0,1,0,1"));
    queryAddColumn(qData, "AppNameBeta", "bit", listToArray("1,1,0,0,1"));

    // create sample sheet
    sheet = spreadsheetNew();
    spreadsheetAddRows(sheet, qData);
    // apply colorized yes/no format
    spreadsheetFormatColumns(sheet, {dataformat='[Green]"Y";;[Red]"N"'}, "1-2");
    spreadsheetWrite(sheet, "c:/path/to/sheet.xls", true);
</cfscript>
```

The "dataformat" uses the first three sections of Excel's custom number formatting: [`<positive><negative><zero>`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-HP001216503.aspx). Translated:

```
 [Green]"Y";   // <positive values>: display "Y" in green
 ;             // <negative values>: do nothing extra
 [Red]"N"      // <zero values>: display "N" in red
```

Comment: Sorry, that's exactly what I am using 'spreadsheet functions' to apply the existing formatting. Had some bad terminology mix-up there on my end. I'll see what I can come up with; again thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Pretty much what Leigh just said. The more I thought about my previous answer, the more I thought it would be better to pass results as a bit instead of text and then handle the formatting in the code, especially if you want to use conditional logic to modify cell colors. Leigh's suggestions are the way to go. :-)

Comment: Shawn - Yeah, this turned out to be one of those "it depends on the goal" type questions :)

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is [SpreadsheetFormatCell()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6747.html)